# Passt "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" zu einer erbrachten Leistung?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Vielleicht denke ich gerade zu viel über Sprache nach, aber mir kommt zur Zeit folgende Situation komisch vor.

> Ich habe meine Thesis abgegeben und von meinem Vater anschließend eine Nachricht erhalten "Herzlichen Glückwunsch".

Ich weiß, dass das im Prinzip nicht falsch ist, es fühlt sich aber irgendwie falsch an. Weil eigentlich passt es in diesem Kontext einfach nicht.

Entweder es geht um den bevorstehenden Prozess der Verteidigung etc. Dann wäre "Wir wünschen dir viel Erfolg" passender. Wenn es um die Würdigung meiner (Arbeits-) Leistung ginge, wäre dann nicht "Wir gratulieren dir" passender?

"Herzlichen Glückwunsch" fühlt sich irgendwie nicht so richtig an. Darum die Frage: Ist mein Sprachgefühl da vielleicht gerade ein wenig zu scharf geschaltet? Oder gibt es aus "germanistischer Sicht" doch eine Erklärung warum "herzlichen Glückwunsch" zu einer erbrachten Leistung passt?

Edit: 
Es spielt wohl sicher eine Rolle, ob der Glückwünschende die erbrachte Leistung würdigt oder für die weitere noch ausstehende Leistung oder einfach nur für die Gutachten das Glück wünscht.

Zur Konkretisierung der Frage, was wären eurer Meinung nach die passendsten Wörter um in einer solchen Situation zu reagieren?

- Glückwunsch
- Gut gemacht
- Bin stolz auf dich
- Weiter so
- ...

Bin gespannt.

Comment: ...kenne ich (nicht von meinem Vater sondern von Muttersprachlern),  hat es mich auch gewundert (denn da hat man noch nicht erfolgreich verteidigt, den Titel erworben, usw.).

Comment: Selbst nach einer erfolgreichen Verteidigung finde ich "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" ziemlich allgemein und nicht passend. Da "ich wünsche dir Glück" irgendwie in die Zukunft gerichtet ist.

Comment: die Frage ist hier, ob dem Antwortenden bewusst ist, dass mit Abgabe der Thesis der akademische Prozess noch nicht abgeschlossen ist.

Comment: Das kann sehr wohl der richtige Ansatz sein.

Comment: Du schilderst Deine Gefühle und fragst uns, wieso es nicht passt oder ob nicht doch? Wieso analysierst Du nicht, aus welchem Grund es Dir nicht passt - woher sollen wir das wissen? Dann spekulierst Du über mögliche Motive und wir sollen eine geeignete Formulierung auswählen oder benennen, ohne dass Du festgelegt hättest, welche Motive denn zu artikulieren sind. Was willst Du eigentlich fragen?

Comment: @user unknown Da ist wohl wieder jemand mit dem falschen Fuß aufgestanden. Jetzt weiß ich wenigstens, wer hier ständig abwertet.

Comment: Die Frage steht relativ eindeutig da: Ist mein Sprachgefühl bezüglich der Verwendung von "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" im Zusammenhang mit einer erbrachten Leistung richtig oder falsch? Als Nebenfrage, welche Wortwahl wäre in einem solchen Fall eigentlich die bessere?

Comment: @Sango: Und soll damit jetzt die Leistung gewürdigt oder die noch ausstehende Leistung oder für das Gutachten Glück gewünscht werden? Du selbst hast ja schon 3 Alternativen genannt. Was passt Dir denn nicht an "Herzlichen Glückwunsch"? Was ist an "Glückwunsch" denn besser? Käme es nicht von Deinem Vater, sondern von der Uni könnte das "herzlich" zu gefühlsbetont sein, aber von Deinem Vater? Ich hatte vermutet Dich störe vielleicht das "Glück", weil es hart erarbeitet ist, nicht Glück, aber dann bringst Du "Glückwunsch", nur ohne "herzlich", als Alternative ein.

Comment: "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" ist doch völlig richtig gewählt von dem Vater. Er will doch nur würdigen, dass die Arbeit geschafft wurde und man nun abgeben konnte, denn dafür war Leistungserbringung und Durchhaltekraft notwendig. Da der Grund klar auf der Hand liegt, finde ich die ganze Frage deswegen irgendwie sehr merkwürdig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es ist schon richtig, dass man, wenn man das Wort "Glückwunsch" in seine Bestandteile zerlegt, nicht zu der Bedeutung einer Gratulation gelangt, aber dennoch sind "Glückwunsch" und "Gratulation" Synonyme, wie ein Blick ins Wörterbuch bestätigt. Und dies nicht erst seit Kurzem. Bei [Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GG20887):

> 1) glückwunsch als reiner wunsch für künftiges wohlergehen ohne den anlasz eines festes oder erfreulichen ereignisses begegnet kaum und nur in jüngerem gebrauch [...]
>
> 3) entsprechend den schon frühen umschreibungen wie gratulatio frolockung oder glückwunsch Frisius (1556) 488a erscheint glückwunsch auch zur ausschlieszlichen bezeugung der mitfreude, der anteilnahme an etwas bereits glücklich abgeschlossenem, erreichtem; ursprünglich hat dabei wohl entsprechend antikem brauch der wunsch mitgespielt, dasz das verhängnis das günstige resultat nicht nachträglich in seinem bestand oder seinen auswirkungen störe; doch kann späterhin von einem mitschwingen dieses gedankens kaum noch die rede sein: [...]

Comment: Sehr interessante Antwort!

Answer (score 10):

Ich bin deutscher Muttersprachler und habe in Deutschland studiert. Wenn jemand eine schwierige Prüfung erfolgreich bestanden oder eine langwierige Abschlussarbeit endlich abgegeben hatte, haben wir uns gegenseitig regelmäßig "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" gewünscht.

Das [Digitale Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gl%C3%BCckwunsch) definiert *Glückwunsch* unter anderem als

> Äußerung der eigenen, freudigen Anteilnahme ... bei einem Erfolg, den ein anderer hat

und gibt als Beispiel den Glückwunsch

> zum bestandenen Examen.

Die in der Frage zitierte Verwendung ist also üblich und richtig (auch wenn der Beispielsatz grammatisch falsch ist).

Answer (score 4):

Ich verstehe das leichte Unbehagen aber Glückwunsch passt m. E. schon. Abgesehen von Tausenden von Karten mit Aufschriften wie *Herzlichen Glückwunsch zur Beförderung*, gibt es im Deutschen nicht viel Auswahl unter den Alternativen:

- *Gratulation* passt denke ich ein bisschen besser, bedeutet aber auch nichts anderes und wird im Duden als *Glückwunsch* erklärt.
- *Chapeau* bzw. *Hut ab* bringen den Aspekt der Anerkennung besser zur Geltung, sind aber deutlich weniger üblich.

Comment: Je mehr ich darüber nachdenke umso mehr zweifel ich an der Sinnhaftigkeit von "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" gerade auch im Bezug zur Beförderung. Weil man wünscht ja nicht Glück zur neuen Aufgabe. 
Den Verweis von Glückwunsch als Synomym für Gratulation finde ich gut. Vielleicht hinterfrage ich da den Sinn des Wortes zu sehr. (Liegt am german.sx ;) )

Answer (score 3):

Ein herzlicher Glückwunsch kann doch beides bedeuten. Ich wünsche dir von Herzen Glück. Das passt zur bevorstehenden Verteidigung. Es beinhaltet aber auch das Glück im Sinne von glücklich sein. Das kannst du nach der geschafften Arbeit und solltest es auch dringend. Deine Zweifel angesichts eines herzlichen Glückwunsches von deinem Vater sprechen ja Bände. Manchmal (vielleicht sogar meistens) geht es überhaupt nicht um die benutzten Wörter. Jedenfalls nicht, wenn der Inhalt wirklich wesentlich ist.

Auch von mir: Herzlichen Glückwunsch!

Comment: Ja, da mag was dran sein. Bei anderen hätte ich darüber wohl nicht soviel nachgedacht. Es kam mir in diesem Zusammenhang ein wenig "flapsig" rüber. Einfach beiläufig unüberlegt.  Darum auch ein wenig die Frage ob ich mit dieser Meinung alleine stehe oder eben nicht.
Danke ;)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the fact that "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" feels wrong in this situation but it depends on the effort (especially the effort present in the mind of the society) which has been put in for instance a thesis.

From my point of view a thesis is always a "big thing" as well for me as for my family and friends.

Taking a look into the Wikimedia definition of "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" (direct quote):
"Redewendung zum Gratulieren bei angenehmen, schönen Anlässen (Geburtstag, Beförderung, Geburt eines Kindes etc.) oder für das Gelingen eines Vorhabens."

Translation for english speaking readers:
"A phrase to congratulate on pleasant, beautiful occasions (birthday, promotion, birth of a child, etc.) or for the success of a project."
It should be fairly obvious now, that the submition of a thesis is some kind of a success, even with no grade on it yet.

As far as iam aware there is in this case no set in stone rule when to use "Herzlichen Glückwunsch" or "Viel Erfolg, Gut gemacht, etc."

Answer (score 2):

Es ist unstrittig, dass man jemandem Glück zu einem **bevorstehenden**, hoffentlich erfolgreichen Abschluss einer bestimmten Sache wünschen kann. Jemandem Glück zu einer **bereits abgeschlossenen** Sache zu wünschen, scheint tatsächlich unlogisch. Allerdings folgt unsere Sprache oft nicht der Logik, insbesondere wenn Widersprüche in der Verwendung bestimmter Ausdrücke durch den häufigen Gebrauch dieser Ausdrücke kaum noch als Widersprüche empfunden werden.

Das häufigste Beispiel dürfte wohl dieses sein:

> Herzlichen Glückwunsch zum Geburtstag!

Logisch betrachtet ist es unsinnig, jemandem Glück für den bereits vergangenen Tag der hoffentlich erfolgreichen Geburt zu wünschen. Dennoch ist das die Standardformel, mit der man jemandem zum Geburtstag gratuliert. Und in Analogie dazu wünscht man eben Glück für alle möglichen Sachen, auch wenn die in der Vergangenheit liegen.

Eine treffendere Formel, um jemandem Anerkennung für eine bereits erbrachte Leistung zu zollen, ist

> Gratulation!

Allerdings empfinde ich es als distanzierter als *Herzlichen Glückwunsch!* Die Wörter *herzlich* und *Wunsch* transportieren mehr Wärme.

Comment: Richtig, es ist die Frage wünscht er Glück in die Zukunft, also zur Verteidigung, oder geht es um die erbrachte Leistung. Ich zweifel ja nicht an den Absichten, sondern frage mich, ob es nicht eine "richtigere" Formel geben müsste.

Comment: Treffender und kürzer ist sicherlich die Formel „Gratulation!“, aber sie ist halt viel seltener.

Comment: Geburtstag ist gerade nicht der Tag der Geburt neunzehnhundertirgendwas, sondern mit dem Geburtstag bezeichnet man im Deutschen meist den wiederkehrenden Kalendertag im Jahr, an dem man feiert. Anlässlich des Jubiläumstags wünscht man Glück - das bedeutet "Glückwunsch zum Geburtstag", nicht dass man zu einem Tag vor 15, 54 oder 90 Jahren etwas feiert oder dem anderen was für die Vergangenheit wünscht - welch bizarre Verrenkung!

Answer (score 0):

We both congratulate on the presently completed work and wish luck for the grade to be received and therefore a Glückwunsch is perfect in all its ambiguity here!

Answer (score 0):

Sprache ist nicht immer rein formal.

"Herzlichen Glückwunsch" ist eher der Wunsch, dass du dich glücklich fühlst.
Das Glück hat hier nichts mit Wahrscheinlichkeiten zu tun, sondern eher das Synonym zu "sehr sehr zufrieden".

Da spielt es keine Rolle, ob es eine rein erarbeitete Leistung ist, reines Glück oder eine Mischung aus beidem.

Auch eine Prüfung hat etwas mit Glück zu tun, denn irgendwo im Stoffgebiet hat die Mehrheit im Regelfall Schwächen.